# Compare Excel data with an Access Database

Tags: excel, ms-access

First off, I'm new with VBA but learning quickly.  I have an Access database that contains part numbers and prices (for the most part).  We use Excel to quote our projects.  I would like to take the part numbers from Excel "look them up" in the Access database and return the price for the corresponding part number and put it in the corresponding cell in Excel.

I have been playing with ADO and the newer ACE OLEDB engine.  I have used sample code to learn about recordset and connecting to the database.  I just don't know how to take it to the next level.  Thanks.

Edit:  I will be developing in Excel/Access 2010, but the majority of the users will be using Excel 2003.  The database currently has 60,000 records.  I need this to be as automated as possible.  Eventually it will turn into a "poor man's" quoting system.  But for now it's just going to be a pricing tool.

Edit2: Chris got me thinking.  I imported the data into the spreadsheet (as long as it doesn't grow much, I should be ok) and will try to keep everything in Excel for now.  I was able to use Vlookup formulas to look at the pricing from a closed wordbook, cool.  What I would like to do now is create a button that when pressed will vlookup all part numbers in say column A (or a range) and return the corresponding prices.  I would like to avoid having formulas in those "prices" cells.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Get External Data to query the data from Access into Excel.  This places a refreshable query link to the db and makes the table available in a sheet in Excel.

Then use a vlookup formula on your quote sheet to look up the part number and return the price.

No need for vba at all.

The details of setting up External Data varies a bit between versions of Excel, if you update your question to include the version I will add some more details of setting it up.

Answer (score 0):

i would do the quoting in ms access as well

it shouldn't b a problem to make a form where a user chooses an item and gets he price onscreen